# How to set controlsource of a textbox from SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a subform bound to a SQL statement. Inside the subform, I have a few text boxes bound to the fields of this SQL. However, I have another text box that needs to be bound to a field from a different SQL statement with criteria from the first one. My code looks like below:

```
Dim subform As Object
Dim formFilter As String

formFilter = "SELECT * FROM my_table_1"
Set subform = Me!my_subform.Form    
subform.RecordSource = formFilter

subform.field1.ControlSource = "tb1f1"
subform.field2.ControlSource = "tb1f2"
...
subform.f3.ControlSource = "= SELECT TOP 1 tb2f3 FROM my_table_2 WHERE tb2f1 = '" & [tb1f1] & "' AND tb2f2 = '" & [tb1f2] "' ORDER BY tb2f4"
```

I cannot use a DLOOKUP function here directly, because I need to sort the table result.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is that subform.f3 simply a display field?

Comment: @HelloW Yes, it is only for display. I don't intend to let the user edit this form directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would simply create a little function to go get the result you want.  It would probably be best to simply rework DLookup in your own function and add sort but I won't do that here.
First the form code.  Notice I am not setting the recordsource, just the value which may not be what you want.

```
subform.f3 = fGet_tb2f3([tb1f1], [tb1f2])
```

Then the function code (put in your own error handling)

```
Public Function fGet_tb2f3(tblf1 as String,tblf2 as String) as String  
    Dim rst as dao.recordset
    Dim db as database
    set db = currentdb
    set rst = db.openrecordset("SELECT TOP 1 tb2f3 FROM my_table_2 WHERE tb2f1 = '" & tb1f1 & "' AND tb2f2 = '" & tb1f2 "' ORDER BY tb2f4",dbopensnapshot
    if not rst is nothing then
        if not rst.eof then fGet_tb2f3 = rst!tb2f3
        rst.close
        set rst = nothing
    end if
    db.close
    set db = nothing
end Function
```

Comment: @HellowW Thanks for your advice. I tried your method. But access prompted me an error 2465 again. The field [tb1f1] and [tb1f2] cannot be found in the statement `subform.f3 = fGet_tb2f3([tb1f1], [tb1f2])`. [tb1f1] and [tb1f2] are just two fields from my subform's record source. what have I missed here?

Comment: @got2nosth The fields you are referencing are in the subform.  My code didn't reflect that.  Is this subform a cascading form or a single record at a time?  If the subform is a single record at a time, it may be best to run this code in the subform in the `on current` event.

Comment: my subform is a datasheet. I tried to call this in the oncurrent event. I still get error 2465 if I do it like this `Me.field4 = getLatestRemark([tb1f1], [tb1f2])`. but it seems to work if I set the controlsource directly like `Me.field4.ControlSource = "=getLatestRemark([tb1f1], [tb1f2])"`. However, the problem now is that whenever I click anywhere in the subform, the field4 column gets refreshed. is there anyway to disable this refresh action?

Comment: I managed to get this to work when I set the controlsource in the form onLoad event. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: It is hard to know unless I understand more about the context of the data and what problem you trying to solve.  Possibly it would be best to make a mental note to check and make sure this behavior is desired.

Comment: Thanks. I am quite happy with this result already. It is working as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't **bind** controls on the same form to 2 different recordsets.  The only thing you could do is **pull** data from 2 different recordsets, but that's probably not the best way to do anything.

In order to do that, you'd have to create a second recordset and grab that value in it.  Something like:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 tb2f3 FROM my_table_2 WHERE tb2f1 = '" & [tb1f1] & "' AND tb2f2 = '" & [tb1f2] "' ORDER BY tb2f4")

Me.MyControlName = rec(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. But I got a run time error 2465 here. It seems Access is not able to refer to my field [tb1f1] and [tb1f2] correctly in the OpenRecordset statement. Here is my code `Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT TOP 1 root_cause FROM Shipment_Remark " _
                               & "WHERE plant = '" & [plant] & "' AND shipment_no = '" & [shipment_no] & "' ORDER BY update_time DESC")
    subform.text_root_cause_field.ControlSource = rs(0)` [plant] and [shipment_no] are two fields from my subform's recordsource.